# write function in RequireJs ,but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using maven requireJS plugin
Before I use requireJS

A button like this

```
<button ... onclick="create()">
<script ... import jquery.ui >
<script>
    function create(){ ... }
</script>
```

After I use requireJS.

```
require(['config'],function(config){
    require(['jquery'],function($d){
        function create(){
            window.location.href="/back/jsps/creditor.jsp";
        }
    });
});
```

JSP file imort the require js

```
<script data-main="${request.contextPath}/../back/javascripts/pages/admin.js" 
src="${request.contextPath}/../back/require.js"></script>
```

But after that, the button doesn't work any more.

Comment: The `create()` function you use as the `onclick` handler is not visible in the global scope, since it's "hidden" inside a module (not sure what you're trying to achieve by declaring it in the <script> tags in the first code block, though). Looks like you have some serious architecture issues, to be honest; search for "unobtrusive JavaScript" for some information on how to separate HTML and JS.

Comment: Yes, I also think create() is in some other function that cause the reason. So I am looking for someone who knows what requirejs do in this example.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit.  If you have a new question, post a new question.